# How DATEADD(DAY,1,TIMESTAMP) SQL in WHERE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I create query

```
SELECT TOP 1 A.TimeStamp FROM dbplc.dbo.PLC_CInputKiln1P1 A 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,1,TimeStamp)) = '2017-04-11' 
AND DATEPART(HOUR,DATEADD(DAY,1,TimeStamp))=7 
ORDER BY TimeStamp
```

result above query this is

> 2017-04-10 07:00:04.450

I want his results like this

> 2017-04-11 07:00:04.450  DAY+1

Comment: `DATEPART(HOUR,DATEADD(DAY,1,TimeStamp))=7` how does adding a day to your result change the hour part of your `datetime` field?

Comment: What is `DAY + 1` in your desired result? Or you just want `SELECT TOP 1 DateAdd(day, 1, A.TimeStamp) ....`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 A.TimeStamp FROM dbplc.dbo.PLC_CInputKiln1P1 A 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,TimeStamp) = '2017-04-11' 
AND DATEPART(HOUR,TimeStamp)=7 
ORDER BY TimeStamp;
```